# Need to access API (https://localhost:8080/er/heartbeats) from another VM

Tags: java, localhost, virtual-machine

I am working on task where I need to access URL https://localhost:8080/er/heartbeat which gave data from heartbeat.xml from other VM.

Need help in this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access "localhost" (127.0.0.1, etc) from another machine.  The 127.x.x.x net range is for host-local use only.  The packets sent to this range are not (should not be) routed outside of this machine / virtual machine.

You need to use an external IP address for this machine or a DNS name that resolves to an external IP address.  (It could be a private IP address, provided that the other VM knows how to route packets to it.)

References:

- [How to view the localhost of another computer in the same network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/157542/how-to-view-the-localhost-of-another-computer-in-the-same-network)
- The Wikipedia page on [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the same network you just need to know the IP of your machine and access it like:

```
 https://other.machine.ip:8080/er/heartbeat
```